# EntityFramework, getting Object ID while added to table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a question. Im adding object to my table in this way:

```
this.db.Objects.Add(new Object { Text = "someText", Number = number });
```

Then, i want to add second object to another table that is related to `Objects` table (table name is `Objects3`)

```
this.db.Objects3.Add(new Object3 { ObjectId = ?, Property = "text" });
```

How to get `Object.Id` (Id in tabel is `int` type) based only on Object's propertys?

Table looks like this:

```
public class Object
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Object2")]
    public int Object2Id { get; set; }
    public Object2 Object2 { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }

    public List<Object3> Objects3 { get; set; }
}

public class Object3
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Object")]
    public int ObjectId { get; set; }
    public Object Object { get; set; }

    public string Property { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I dont know, how to check it? I just have DbContext class, DbSets. I make migratio and update-database, nothing more. I belive it is simple auto increment Id because when i adding something to database (but from another table) it have unique `Id`. Now, i must find that `Id` from added `Object`

Comment: Maybe we can find that `Object` (as `object` from List) by their propertys?

Comment: Try to call `SaveChanges()` after adding first object and its `Id` column should be filled: `var obj = new Object() {...}; this.db.Objects.Add(obj); this.db.SaveChanges(); var obj3 = new Object3() { ObjectId = obj.Id, ...};`

Comment: How i will get `Object.Id` when i didnt init it by myself but by `AutoIncrement` from sql database?

Comment: ok, i will try. Thanks!

Comment: @RomanDoskoch but what when i will jump outside class that im using `var obj`? How i will find that specific `var obj` that i added while before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need values of IDs to create a relation between two entities, this is where the ORM's support for navigation properties becomes handy:

```
var o1 = new Object() { ...
var o3 = new Object3() { ...

o3.Object = o1;

this.db.Objects3.Add( o3 );

this.db.SaveChanges();
```

EF should notice your navigation property has an object at the other end and save both to the database, in proper order, and set both IDs accordingly.

However, if you insist on having the ID in an explicit way, you should first save changes so that the ID is set in the object

```
var o1 = new Object() { ...
this.db.Objects.Add( o1 );

this.db.SaveChanges(); 

var id = o1.ID;
```

Now you can use your ID in an explicit way.

A side note - your navigation properties lack `virtual` modifier, this will make it impossible for the EF to replace the default implementation with the lazy-loading one for objects that are materialized when queries are executed against the database.

```
public class Object
{
    public Object()
    {
        this.Objects3 = new List<Object3>();
    }

    public virtual ICollection<Object3> Objects3 { get; set; }
}

public class Object3
{
    public virtual Object Object { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! But what if i want to navigate to `var o1` in another class? How to finde that `o1.Id`? is it possible or i need to pass `Id` somehow?

Comment: What do you mean by "navigate"?

Comment: What if i want to find that `o1` in another class, becuase i checked it, there is no problem to get proper `Id` like you write in your answer in one class, but what when i add `o1` how to find that `o1.Id` in second class?

Comment: For example, i add `o1` in class `Class1`, then i want to get somehow `o1.Id` in Class2` methods

Comment: Use navigation properties, `o2.Object.Id`, assuming you save changes to the database and id is set.